# Buttons showing 0 references winForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I am just testing with the buttons and textboxes when I found that 2 buttons and a textbox isn't doing anything while the 2 buttons are working just fine.

`0 references` is showing over these buttons

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            
}
```

The buttons does exist in Form (Design).
those which are working shows 1 references

Comment: Either Visual Studio is having a funny moment, or you've not actually assigned the event to the control in the events tab for the control. My money is on the second one since you also said it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because the method `button1_Click`  <sub>(please name your buttons something better; it takes just a couple of seconds to rename a button after you add it to a form)</sub> exists in Form1.cs does *not* mean it's wired up to be the button click handler

- Stop the app if it is running,
- go into the forms designer,
- get properties on the button (click on it and look in the grid in the right, or right click and choose properties if no grid is showing under solution explorer),
- click the lightning bolt at the top of the properties grid,
- scroll to the Click line,
- drop down the setting to the right of the click and choose `button1_Click`
- repeat for other unlinked buttons
- ps this is how you can link multiple controls to the same handler

Oh, and take the time to rename all your buttons, so they are called like `saveButton`, `cancelButton` - it'll make your program a lot easier to read both for yourself and others you ask for help from eg on SO. Then rename your click handlers by focusing the caret on the method name and pressing Ctrl-R-R. Files like Form1 can be renamed and if the class inside them is also called Form1 then VS will offer to rename the class too, bonus! :)